# What does the word 「よりうけ」 mean?

Tags: words, parsing, renyōkei, particle-より

Here is the sentence including the word.

> 生{せい}活{かつ}費{ひ}そのほかいっさいのせわを丹{たん}下｛げ｝氏{し}**よりうけ**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

より means "from" (similar to から).
うけ(受け) is the 連用形 form of 受ける, "to receive", "to be given", etc.